# Что означает auto...... в параметре функции?

Tags: c++, задание-на-собеседовании

Что означает следующее объявление функции?

```
void foo(auto......);
```

Comment: недостаточно данных в вашем вопросе. ответить невозможно.

Comment: @AlexGlebe почему недостаточно? Что надо добавить?

Comment: Непонятно, почему закрыли? Вроде нормальный вопрос. Это эквивалентно вот такому объявлению: `template <typename ...P> void foo(P ...p, ...)`. Т.е. это variadic шаблон с переменным числом аргументов, и плюс с сишным `...`-аргументом в конце.

Answer (score 1):

Это эквивалентно вот такому объявлению: `template <typename... T> void foo(T..., ...);`. Т.е. это variadic шаблон с переменным числом аргументов, и плюс с сишным ...-аргументом на конце.